# Why did my question (about a program with no web interface) get migrated to Webapps?

Tags: discussion, migration

[LINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(application)) is a program that runs on Windows, Android, iOS.
LINE has no web interface at all, in fact its website only shows static help pages. You can't even login or create an account via their website.

So, when I asked [a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100139/line-verify-your-identity-an-error-has-occurred-please-try-again-later) about LINE, I hesitated between SuperUser and Android, finally opting for the latter because my question is about the interaction between the desktop app and the Android app.

I was quite surprised to discover that my question got migrated to Webapps, the most unlikely place for it.

Was it a mistake? Or am I missing some information?

Comment: Question history on SU: http://superuser.com/posts/1142615/revisions

Comment: Just FYI , the image in your question shows it running on a cell phone, the error message is on the cell phone, and you have an Android tag.  I voted to migrate it to the Android site because it appeared to be an issue with a phone app.  You might want to add more detail to the question to clarify what LINE is and how it's a PC issue.

Comment: @fixer1234: The picture actually shows the desktop software side-to-side with the Android app. The desktop app does not have grey buttons and drop-downs and other typical Windows UI widgets, which makes it not obvious that it is desktop software, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is not on-topic on Webapps and I don't see any reason why it is off-topic here I have reopened it.

If you want it migrated to Android instead then let me know, but the cross-platform nature of the application suggests that it is better on SU to me.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the migration voters did so because of this part:

> app running as a Chrome addon

People who don't know what LINE is will think that means it's a web thing (it is running in a browser). LINE does communicate across all the various devices through servers on the Internet, but so do IRC clients, and like you said, there's not currently a web interface, though historically there used to be (source: Wikipedia):

> At one point Line was available as a website (non-browser-app), but that has been discontinued.

I believe your question would do well on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/). At the moment, I don't have a strong opinion one way or the other on whether Super User considers browser apps to be on-topic applications, but if it does, then your question is fine here too because it's about the interaction between that app and something else.

At least [one commenter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100139/line-verify-your-identity-an-error-has-occurred-please-try-again-later#comment87222_100139) on Web Apps agrees that migration there wasn't optimal:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a web application. It should not have been migrated from Super User.